# Accessing an Element by Custom Attribute - JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, attributes

I am trying to hide an element by selecting its custom attribute. What I am doing is not finding the element.

Thanks

Example below also here ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/castonzo/LM2mp/1/))

```
<p>
<a href="#" 
   data-dialog-id="rosterModal" 
   data-dialog-title="Roster Confirmation" 
   class="btn blue js-openDialog">My Link to Hide</a>
</p>
<p>
  <button id="hideBtn">Hide</button>
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#hideBtn').click(function() {
        var myLink = $("a[data-dialog-id='rosterModal']");
        myLink.hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Well, you are trying to bind the event handler to `#hideme` but the button's ID is `hideBtn`.

Comment: And in the fiddle you also have a typo in the data attribute

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about typos


Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem is using the wrong ID (basically a typo). This question is not going to be of much use for anyone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pretty much had it.

1. Your `a` tag attribute in JSFiddle was `data-dislog-id` (typo)
2. Your selector is looking for `#hideme` which should be `#hideBtn`

Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/LM2mp/3/

Comment: thanks - totally missed that typo

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like `hideme` is an ID in your form. I think you want `hideBtn` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Wrong button id

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#hideBtn').click(function() {
        var myLink = $("[data-dialog-id='rosterModal']");
        $(myLink).hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#hideBtn').click(function() {
  var myLink = $("a[data-dialog-id='rostermodal']");
    console.log(myLink)
    myLink.hide();
});
```

here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LM2mp/7/